# Multiple Id's and one image

Tags: jquery

Is there a clean way in jQuery to do a conditional statement that removes shows an image based on ID. I tried a statement and keep getting results of the one I need and this image instead.

```js
//Text Hover to view image in Departments/Shopping
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('html').attr('id') == 'appleStoreMenuLabel') {
    $(this.id).hover(
      function() {
        $("#appleStoreLogo").show();
      },
      function() {
        $("#appleStoreLogo").hide();
      }
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
  <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel">
            Apple Store</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel1">iPods
                </a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel2">iPod
                    Accessories </a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel3">Watches</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel4">Mac
                    Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel5">iPads</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel6">Shop
                    All Apple Store</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Use class instead ID

Comment: Where is the element with an id of `appleStoreLogo` in the HTML?

Comment: Note that `$(this.id)` doesn't select anything because there is likely no element `<appleStoreMenuLabel></appleStoreMenuLabel>` in your document. If you want to select by id, use `$("#" + this.id)`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so I could theoretically keep the same code block, just  concat the # with this.id?

Comment: The `this` you are referencing is `document`. Can confirm yourself `console.log(this)`

Comment: Theoretically... no. :) Because apparently your `html` element has an id of "appleStoreMenuLabel", and so does the `a` tag you've shown here. Ids must be using to the document. Change one to a class or just a different name. I will say that @dustytrash's advice is sound; it is better to use classes than ids.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you.  It looks like yours fixed my problem with out much refactoring.

Comment: @HereticMonkey question.  The logic I have now with using # + this.id on hover works, but when I add an OR for the same condition but different ID, it doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class, not ID.

Change your HTML `id=appleStoreMenuLabel1`, `id=appleStoreMenuLabel2` ... to use `class=appleStoreMenuLabel`

Then change your JS to something like this:

```
$('.appleStoreMenuLabel').hover(function () {
        $("#appleStoreLogo").show();
    },
    function() {
        $("#appleStoreLogo").hide();
});
```

**Update**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="iPods" class="appleStoreMenuLabel">iPods</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="iPodAccessories" class="appleStoreMenuLabel">iPod Accessories </a></li>
    <li><a href="searchResults.html" id="watches" class="appleStoreMenuLabel">Watches</a></li>
    ...
</ul>

<!-- somewhere on your page -->
<img id="iPodAccessoriesimage" />
<img id="iPodsimage" />
<img id="watchesimage" />

$('.appleStoreMenuLabel').hover(function (event) {
            $("#" + event.target.id + "image").show();
        },
        function() {
            ("#" + event.target.id + "image").hide();
    });
```

Comment: <div><img src="C:\Users\username\Documents\apple.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="appleStoreLogo"style="display: block"></div>

Comment: Jquery `.hover` has two handler function which is called when a mouse enters and leaves the element. Use that. instead of if condition inside `$('.appleStoreMenuLabel').hover(function () { //show}, function(){ //hide}`

Comment: Note that you can also do `$("#appleStoreLogo").toggle($('appleStoreLogo').is(":visible"));`

Comment: Appreciate it, but I have several tags pointing to the same image, that is where I run into that problem.

Comment: @DoubleUTee I'm assuming your first comment was in response to my comment on your question? If so, please edit your question to include the HTML in relation to the HTML you've already presented.

Comment: @dustytrash what attributes would I add in appleStoreMenu if I switch it to a class?  Just display?

Comment: @DoubleUTee I updated my answer, is that what you meant? Personally I'd just use a different function for each image if so